# How to selectively apply syntax highlight 

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a tutorial/book with Vim, and I'd like to turn off the syntax highlighting for a block of text (the normal text of the book) and reactivate it for the code examples.

I have Googled to no end, but I cannot find a simple solution. Am I missing something? Or is this not achievable in Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written the [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) for that (my main use case is highlighting patches inside emails as with the "diff" syntax). With it, you can `:[range]SyntaxIgnore` or `:[range]SyntaxInclude {filetype}` certain sections of a buffer, or, when the sections start and end with certain markers, define dynamic sections that adapt when the number of lines change.

Comment: Great! this is exactly what I was looking for ! just one little issue when using the tags (e.g. @begin=ruby@ ) in macvim a print PDF will display these tags in the final file. Is there any way to hide these? I used call SyntaxRange#Include('@begin=ruby@', '@end=ruby@', 'ruby', 'NonText')

Comment: Well, what's in the text will be printed. You could temporarily remove them (`:g/^@\(begin\|end\)=ruby@$/d`, then undo after printing.

Comment: thanks Ingo but if I do that on macvim the highlight disappear so I cannot print anymore (print as per generate pdf that on macvim is done via the print function). Any idea is much appreciate or well I can leave the tag. Thanks a lot for your plugin !

Comment: Ah, so you want to print with the highlighting. Well, instead of the barely visible `NonText`, you could try to define an "invisible" highlight group `:hi Hide guifg=white guibg=NONE`, and use that. The tags will still be there, but hopefully white-on-white. Apart from that (and to get rid of the emptied tag lines), you'd have to remove the tags and use `:[range]SyntaxInclude` manually over those lines.

Comment: thanks a lot. Best solution seems to use an appropriate color scheme that works well with printing. I did try over 50 templates and the best (that makes the tags very light and non-intrusive) is mayansmoke

Answer (score 3):

You can create a syntax file for your book.

For example, you can create a script: `~/.vim/syntax/tutor.vim`

```
"
" tutor.vim -- syntax file for my book/tutor
"
syn include @PY $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/python.vim
syn region pyBlock start="{{{" end="}}}" contains=@PY
```

---

This is a sample file:

```
# File: intro.txt
# Date: 2012-08-19

blah, blah ...
So, I will show you some code:
{{{
    def hello():
        print "world"
}}}

# vim: set syn=tutor :
```

Comment: wow thank you this seems very nice and simple. I assume that for Ruby I just replace python with ruby? what the contains=@PY does ? (thinking about how to replace that)

Comment: You can change `@PY` to `@RB` (whatever you want). It's just a name. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thinking tangentially...

How about using something like restructured text or markdown within Vim and render on github. This gives you version management for free. You can have code-blocks.

Comment: Well you can have version management regardless (e.g. if you use a syntax file) but your idea is interesting. What will you use and how? just markdown with code blocks ?

Comment: I like writing in markdown and then converting with [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). You can even make it into a PDF, HTML, ebook, LaTeX, whatever.